# Как посчитать одним запросом количество соответствий условию при выборке в mySQL?

Tags: mysql

Создавать для каждого COUNT(field_x) запрос, думаю как-то не рационально и громоздко. Попробовал такую вот конструкцию, приведу пример:

```
SELECT COUNT(`field_1`), COUNT(`field_2`), COUNT(`field_3`)
FROM (SELECT `field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`, `field_4`
FROM `table_name` WHERE `date_field`="01.01.2017"
AND (`field_1`="data_1" OR `field_1`="data_2" OR `field_1`="data_3"))
sub
WHERE `field_1`="data_1" AND `field_2`="data_2"
```

Срабатывает, но счётчик выдаёт количество из последнего поля field_2="data_2":

```
COUNT(`field_1`) | COUNT(`field_2`)  
-----------------------------------
      1          |        1
```

по факту должно быть (хотелось бы получить такую таблицу):

```
COUNT(`field_1`) | COUNT(`field_2`)
-----------------------------------
      3          |        1
```

---

Возможно ли одним запросом такое реализовать? Счётчиков в рабочем коде у меня 7 штук.

Comment: ``select sum(`field_1`="data_1"), sum(`field_2`="data_2") from ...``

Comment: @PetSerAl - спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Можно подзапросами. Например :

```
    SELECT COUNT(table1.columnName),(SELECT COUNT(table2.columnName) FROM table2 LIMIT 1), (SELECT COUNT(table3.columnName) FROM table3 LIMIT 1) FROM table1
```

или можно даже имя столбца не использовать а так `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Даже на первый взгляд как-то громоздко выглядит.